# Is it enough to check the Audience of OAuth2 Access tokens?

Tags: authentication, openid-connect, oauth2

I am investigating using Social Login for a web service fronted by Web-based portals and Mobile applications.  The idea is to "Authenticate" the user and let the service create an "API-Key" once the user has been Authenticated.

I am Looking at OpenID/OpenID connect/OAuth 2.

The last paragraph of [section 10.16 of RFC6749](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-10.16) states:

> Authenticating resource owners to clients is out of scope for this
> specification.  Any specification that uses the authorization process
> as a form of delegated end-user authentication to the client (e.g.,
> third-party sign-in service) MUST NOT use the implicit flow without
> additional security mechanisms that would enable the client to
> determine if the access token was issued for its use (e.g.,
> audience-restricting the access token).

And [Google states](https://developers.google.com/identity/protocols/OAuth2UserAgent#validatetoken) that to Avoid the so-called Confused Deputy Problem you must validate Access tokens.  This consists of checking that the intended Audience matches your own Client-ID.

The problem as I see it is that the client-ID can still be harvested by a malicious app or person and used in a malicious public client to obtain access tokens that would "check-out" for your client.

Facebook allows you to [Enable an option to require appsecret_proof](https://developers.facebook.com/docs/graph-api/securing-requests#appsecret_proof) and states:

> Access tokens are portable. It's possible to take an access token
> generated on a client by Facebook's SDK, send it to a server and then
> make calls from that server on behalf of the person. An access token
> can also be stolen by malicious software on a person's computer or a
> man in the middle attack. Then that access token can be used from an
> entirely different system that's not the client and not your server,
> generating spam or stealing data.
>
> You can prevent this by adding the appsecret_proof parameter to every
> API call from a server and enabling the setting to require proof on
> all calls. This prevents bad guys from making API calls with your
> access tokens from their servers. If you're using the official PHP
> SDK, the appsecret_proof parameter is automatically added.

This approach seems no better - a malicious public client (having obtained and using your legitimate Client-ID) can still perform the login process and then harvest the portable access token to submit to your web service (secure client) which would include the appsecret_proof parameter.

Or am I missing something.  Do I need to give up on OAuth2 / OpenID Connect?